# Calling method from overridden Java class.

Tags: groovy

I have a problem with calling an overriden method from java class.
I have the following Java class:

```
public class Base
{
    int state = 0;
    public void called()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, from called method: " + state);
    }

    public String getFirst() 
    {
       return "From Base;
     }

    //
    ...
    //
}
```

I use a groovy script to override `getFirst()` that so that it calls `called()`

```
def base = [ getFirst : {
    called()                    // this line has an error
    "From Second"
    }] as Base

base.getFirst()
```

How do I implement the this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the proxy magic in that way... At the time of the Maps declaration, it doesn't know it's going to be a Proxy for Base, so it will throw the error

Why not just do it the normal way?

```
 def base = new Base() {
   public String getFirst() {
     called()
     "from me"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hm, it works. Thanks, I googled over one hour and find that overriding in groovy implemented only with closures.